# android correct lifecycle to update between two activities

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, lifecycle

I have this in a fragment to set visible or invisible a textview:

```
startText = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.starting_text);
/** GET SHARED PREF VALUE */
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("prefN_b", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
nnS = sharedPreferences.getInt("numB", DEFAULT);
Log.d("THIS", Integer.toString(nnS));

if (nnS > 0){
  startText.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
}else{
  startText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
```

and in another activity i update shared pref with this:

```
/** GET SHARED PREF VALUE */
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("prefN_b", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    nnS = sharedPreferences.getInt("numB", DEFAULT);

    /** GET TITLE FROM DATABASE */
    DatabaseConnector dbConnector = new DatabaseConnector(this);
    dbConnector.open();
    Cursor c = dbConnector.ListAllNotes();
    itemNN = c.getCount();

    /** SAVE/UPDATE SHARED PREF VALUE */
    SharedPreferences.Editor editorr = sharedPreferences.edit();
    editorr.putInt("numB", itemNN);
    editorr.commit();
```

right now are both placed under onCreate of respective activities, so this only update upon app restart, i'd like it to work upon moving from activity to activity, where should i place the codes? i tried onPause and onRestart combination but didn't work.. thanks

**SOLVED:**
AS @Mobile Developer suggests below I placed both codes in respectives onResume(). In the fragment onResume() I had to modify the textview fetch to: `startText = (TextView) this.getActivity().findViewById(R.id.starting_text);`

Comment: Did you try onResume()?

Comment: onResume() is good choose.

Comment: @MobileDeveloper it works thanks! i placed both codes in respectives onResume(). In the fragment onResume I had to modify the textview fetch to: `startText = (TextView) this.getActivity().findViewById(R.id.starting_text);`

Answer (score 0):

You could add a preference listener (registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener) in your first activity that updates the TextView's visibility when the preference changes.

Additionally as Mobile Developer mentioned, you could check the preference in the first activity's onResume() and update your TextView there.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't use startActivityForResult(@Intent intent, @int requestCode) instead of startActivity(@Intent)
And data from second activity will receive in onActivityResult(in first activity)